# Simple Json issue datatype

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to workout this simple json issue in Python but just can't work out where im going wrong. I have tried using json.dumps() but just either get unicode object has no attribute get or str has not attribute get.

heres my code

```
import urllib2
import json

url = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
request = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
data = response.read()
js = json.loads(data)
json = json.dumps(js)

for item in json:
    #print item['top']['buyorders'][0]["price"]
    print item.get('top').get('buyorders')[0].get['price']
```

Comment: Using a variable name that's the same as a module name is a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do the dump, pass the response directly to [json.load()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) and iterate over the produced python dictionary:

```
data = json.load(response) 
for key, value in data.iteritems():
    ...
```